# low cpu idle time in linux system

Tags: linux, unix, linux-kernel, operating-system

I have seen low cpu idle time in top command. Will this low idle time cause any issue with application? Normally it's above 20% or 30%.

Also system time is using above 70%.

```
top - 15:17:16 up 55 days, 14:27,  4 users,  load average: 102.27, 103.70, 104.21
Tasks: 454 total,  31 running, 418 sleeping,   0 stopped,   5 zombie
Cpu(s): 28.8%us, 70.4%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.7%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  16395276k total, 16321964k used,    73312k free,   118016k buffers
Swap: 18874360k total,      548k used, 18873812k free,  4635752k cached
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find complete details of all the stats that are displayed by top.  http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2015/02/24/understanding-linuxs-cpu-stats

An excerpt from the above link

> the *id* statistic tell us that the processor was idle just over 73% of the time during the last sampling period. The total of the user space percentage - **us**, the niced percentage - **ni**, and the idle percentage - **id**, should be close to 100%. Which it is in this case. If the CPU is spending a more time in the other states then something is probably awry.

Now, regarding your question, it seems you are running a quite heavy computing job on your system. It can be a heavy IO operation as well.
Though, generally the **sys** percentage does not rise more than 1-2% and should be as low as possible.

> This number can peak much higher, especially when there is a lot of I/O happening.

Also, just a simple while loop in bash, `while true; do cat Makefile>/dev/null; done` results in the usage of 20% of cpu time in the kernel space(mentioned by **sys**).

```
%Cpu(s): 16.1 us, 17.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 66.1 id,  0.3 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
```

> High kernel usage - Sometimes this is acceptable. For example a program that does lots of console I/O can cause the kernel usage to spike. However if it remains higher for long periods of time then it could be an indication that something isn't right. A possible cause of such spikes could be a problem with a driver/kernel module.

Try to find a process/daemon that may be causing such overuse of CPU. If it remains permanent then troubleshoot the running processes.